# Importing Payment SDK JAR in JDE

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Can you help me in this?

I want to import the `Payment SDK Jar v.18` in my Blackberry JDE project. I follow the following steps:

1) In the BlackBerry Java Development Environment, in the Files pane, right-click on the project that you want to
add the library to and click "Properties".

2) Open BUILD tab

3) In the section: Imported jar files: `Click Add`

4) Navigate to the location where you extracted the Payment Service SDK and double-click the `paymentapi.jar` file.

5) Click OK

6) Run Emulator

On launching my app I see this error:

> Error starting yourGPSapp: Module 'MODULE_NAME' has verification
>   errors.

Can you please tell me why I am getting this error?
-Thanks in advance.

Comment: My fault - you're getting error on start not on compile phase. I didn't find from what OS version do they support. What is your JDE version and what is your device OS version?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the error on launching the app.                    JDE version: 7.0.0.34 Using Emulator: RIM BB9900-7.0.0.261

Comment: Most probably it's not related to payment.jar. Chek this out http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Module-has-verification-errors-Error-starting-using-Eclipse-3-5/td-p/402438

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Adding JAR as a file, fixed the verification errors. http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Compile_a_JAR_file_into_a_BlackBerry_Library.html?nodeid=801017&vernum=0